# Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR [object Object] VUE JS,NODE

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I am using vuejs as my frontend,when I run npm run serve,it runs ok,but when I navigate to my browser,the first thing I see is this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TibX.png)

Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
[object Object]
handleError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:252:58
createOverlay/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:275:18

I have tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling with npm install,but the error is still there,please assits,any assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your network tab, there might be 404 request

Answer (score -1):

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: {
        errors: true,
        warnings: false,
        runtimeErrors: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```